# Javascript: Correct syntax for making editable custom properties (on click, toggle colour of Leaflet GeoJSON object)

Tags: javascript, properties, leaflet, geojson, polyline

I've written the following javascript code using leaflet to make multiple red polylines with each having property called "active" which starts as true.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < railLinks.length; i++) {
        var polyline = new L.geoJSON(railLinks[i].polyline, {
          linkNumber: railLinks[i].linkNumber,
          active: true, //THIS LINE DOESNT DO WHAT I THOUGHT IT WOULD
          style: function(active) {
            return {
              weight: 2,
              color: 'red'
            };
          }
        }).addTo(map);
        
        polyline.on('click', function() {
          set = !this.active
          this.active = set;
          this.setStyle({
            color: getColor(set)
          });
          
        });
    }
    
    function getColor(x) {
      return x  ?   'black':
                    '#888888';
    };
```

I'm tring to implement a toggle so that when you click a true polyline it turns to false and vice versa.

With this I would expect the first click to make grey ("false"), then black, then grey etc. Instead the first click makes black (representing true), suggesting the initial state was not true.

I would imagine the problem is with my syntax and that

```
active: true
```

is not the same property being changed as the later

```
this.active
```

as I can set the first active to any value without affecting the on click behaviour. Any ideas what this should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone's information who comes across a similar problem, I've now solved my issue with the code below:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < railLinks.length; i++) {
        var polyline = new L.geoJSON(railLinks[i].polyline, {
          linkNumber: railLinks[i].linkNumber,
        }).addTo(map);
        polyline.active = true;
        polyline.setStyle({
            weight: 2,
            color: 'red'
        });
        polyline.on('contextmenu', function() {
          set = !this.active
          this.active = set;
          this.setStyle({
            color: getColor(set)
          });
        });
    }
    
    function getColor(x) {
      return x ? 'black':'#888888';
    };
```